# Wait for a clicked() event in while loop in Qt

Tags: python, qt

How can I wait, at each iteration, within a for loop, that the user press a given QPushButton?

```
for i in range(10):


        while (the button has not been pressed):
            #do nothing
        #do something
```

The main problem is that I cannot catch the clicked() event in the while loop.

**EDIT:**

Finally I ended up with:

```
 for i in range(10):
        self.hasBeenProcessed = False

        # only one function can modify this boolean
        # and this function is connected to my button
        while (self.hasBeenProcessed is not True):
                QtCore.QCoreApplication.processEvents()
```

Comment: use the event of your button it should have a clicked event, so implement a slot and connect them. See also ->  https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_Use_QPushButton/de

Comment: and why would you use a while loop to do nothing? could it be that you try to start a multithreaded application and wait in your while loop for an event?

Comment: Because I do not want to go to the next iteration until I receive the clicked() event.

Comment: Hmmm, i think you should rethink about the signals and slots technology, and maybe you could use them in another way to solve your problem?! Because i think they really offer you the solution you are looking for...

Comment: I know how signals and slots work. You can see the clicked() event as a blocking event inside a function.

Comment: So maybe you could add your source code here?

Comment: "How can I wait?" You don't wait. You get informed when the user has clicked the button by connecting to its `clicked` signal. If you need to run some code in the background in the main (GUI) thread, you can do so by attaching the code to a zero-timeout timer.

Comment: As to go to the next iteration I need to process the current iteration within another function, I added a class boolean variable "hasBeenProcessed" which is set to True once the said function is finished. See my edit for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I share the slight skepticism as to whether you should want to be doing what you described. Also, I share that it would be better if you show a bit more code to describe the context.

Having said this, the code below is a stab at what you seem to be describing. Note that this is by no means meant to be production-ready code, but more a crude example to illustrate the principle.

What happens is that I call one function on the press of `Button1` and I keep the event loop spinning inside the `while` loop by calling `QCoreApplication.processEvents()` which means that the GUI will still accept e.g. mouse events. Now, this is something that you should *not* typically do. There are, however, certain situations where this can be needed, e.g. if you have a non-modal `QProgressDialog` and you want to keep the GUI updating while the dialog counter increases (see e.g. http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qprogressdialog.html#value-prop)

Then the second part is only to modify the global variable in the second function when you press button 2 and the `while` loop will exit.

Let me know if this helps

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

btn2pushed = False

def window():
   app = QApplication(sys.argv)
   win = QDialog()
   b1 = QPushButton(win)
   b1.setText("Button1")
   b1.move(50,20)
   b1.clicked.connect(b1_clicked)

   b2 = QPushButton(win)
   b2.setText("Button2")
   b2.move(50,50)
   QObject.connect(b2,SIGNAL("clicked()"),b2_clicked)

   win.setGeometry(100,100,200,100)
   win.setWindowTitle("PyQt")
   win.show()
   sys.exit(app.exec_())

def b1_clicked():
   print "Button 1 clicked"
   i = 0
   while ( btn2pushed != True ):
       # not doing anything                                                                                                                                                                                                   
       if ( i % 100000 == 0 ):
           print "Waiting for user to push button 2"
       QCoreApplication.processEvents()
       i += 1;

   print "Button 2 has been pushed"


def b2_clicked():
    global btn2pushed
    btn2pushed = True

if __name__ == '__main__':
   window()
```

Comment: I solved it few hours ago thanks to QCoreApplication.processEvents() before seeing your answer. And your answer confirm that it was the way to solve it!

Comment: I found it works ,but comsume a lot CPU because of the while loop, is there a cheap way to realize it?

Comment: @bactone, as again a rather simplistic approach, you can probably reduce the CPU consumption by introducing a small sleep into the loop, basically just reducing the repetition rate of the loop. There will be a trade-off between the application being still responsive and CPU consumption going down.